# installation of aikau on alfresco 5.1 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: alfresco, aikau

I have installed Alfresco 5.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and my
   challenge is to install aikau and amp files, by default i see the jar
   files in the lib folder

Answer (score 4):

Have you read [this](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2015/03/24/why-alfresco-5-0-d-will-be-a-game-changer-for-ui-development/) blog post. There is no installation process for Aikau. You can just drop any Aikau JAR into the WEB-INF/lib folder of Share. JARs can be downloaded from [here](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~aikau).

If you're building an AMP file then you should just declare the version of Aikau that you want to use as a Maven dependency. The [Alfresco SDK](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/alfresco-sdk-intro.html) is an ideal way to build AMPs and comes with support for Aikau built in.

Comment: Ok thank you for the response. How then shall it appear on Alfresco repository? In the lib folder there is an aikau jar file, but i cant access it from my alfresco repository. When you install 5.1 latest its already included..

Comment: Aikau should not be placed in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the "alfresco" WAR - it does not run on the Repository application, it is used by the Share application (so should be placed in the share.war). I don't understand what you mean by "I can't access it" - how are you trying to access it?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I was hoping to see it on the alfresco main menu. How can I access it ?

Comment: What are you hoping to see exactly? What are you trying to access? Aikau is a UI framework that you can use to develop pages for Alfresco... the header bar is created via Aikau as is the search page.

Comment: May be my question is, how do we use it in alfresco? suppose i want edit a certain script.

Comment: I would suggest that you work through the Aikau tutorial on GitHub https://github.com/Alfresco/Aikau/blob/master/tutorial/chapters/Contents.md and read back through my blog posts to get a good understand of what it is all about https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/author/ddraper/